# Python: DateTime-Objects can be plotted in matplotlib, but only sometimes?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, datetime, matplotlib

So, I made a DataFrame that looks like this:

[image]

The DF ist chronologically ordered by the DateTime-Objects. These DateTimes are generated by transforming the column "attributes.timestamp" which contains timestamps as strings:

```
df["DateTime"] = df["attributes.timestamp"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ'))
```

The corresponding y-values is a counter that counts objects within the corresponding minute. 
When I try to plot this DF in matplotlib, it actually works. It takes the datetime-objects as x-values and plots the counts for that minute as follows:

[image]

Now of course it looks dumb to have to full DateTime-object shown on the x-axis. It shows month, day and hour in this order (in the example it's the 2nd of March from 2pm to 20pm). I want it to show JUST the hours (or at least just the time, not the entire date that comes with it). So I tried to add a new column (called "Time") to the DF. That column would extract the time from the DateTime column using the following code:

```
df["Time"] = df["DateTime"].time()
```

However, that doesn't work, for it gives me the attribute error "'Series' object has no attribute 'time'". Instead I tried something else. I just repeated the whole code I used earlier when I generated the DateTime objects and added ".time()" to it.

```
df["Time"] = df["attributes.timestamp"].apply(lambda x: datetime.strptime(x, '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%SZ').time())
```

I have no idea why, but now it works just fine. I was capable of adding the time from my Datetime-object:

[image]

My next idea would be to use the "Time" column on my x-axis instead of the whole datetime for plotting. y-values from the counter stay the same. But for some reason that doesn't work. When I try to plot it like that, it gives me the following error: TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time' 
Strangely enough that was no problem when plotting with the whole DateTime-object. I don't know, why the exctracted time would be a problem, since it is a chronologically ordered value as well.

My question is: Why the heck does my approach not work? And: Is there any way to go around this?

Comment: `df["Time"] = df["DateTime"].dt.time`

Comment: that does indeed also extract the time. When plotting it on the x-axis it still gives me the same error though: 
TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'datetime.time'

Comment: The api isn’t built to handle datetime.time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matplotlib supports plotting pandas DatetimeIndex, as well as numpy `datetime64` objects, but not sequences of `datetime.time`. In addition, `df["Time"] = df["DateTime"].time()` does not work because you are applying the `.time()` method to the Series itself, instead of to the elements of the Series within, which are `pandas.Timestamp` objects that do have the `.time()` method defined.

To answer your main question, you just want the x-axis to not show redundant info, yes? Instead of creating a new column only for itme, the proper way to do this is to format the matplotlib x-axis with `matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter`.

Here's a minimal example:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

# Example DatetimeIndex and data
x = pd.date_range(start='2020-05-10', end='2020-05-11', freq='1h')
y = list(range(len(x)))

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
plt.plot(x, y)

# The following specifies the format for dates
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
date_fmt = mdates.DateFormatter('%I: %M%p')
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(date_fmt)

# autofmt_xdate helps with auto-rotating dates so they do not overlap
fig.autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

As for how to know what string to pass to `DateFormatter`, refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior for `strftime` formats.

Matplotlib has a page dedicated to fixing common date annoyances that you might find useful: https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/gallery/recipes/common_date_problems.html

Comment: Thanks mate, you really helped me out big time! Would give you a thumbs up, if I could. But it wont let me :P